# How to add a custom taxonomy to show up in a custom post type menu?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, add-submenu-page

I really don't know hot to ask this question correctly. I've created a custom post type with a name badges and added custom taxonomies to it (level, skill). Now I want to add a new submenu item to that custom post. 
This is my custom post:

```
  add_action('init', 'bsp_badges_register');
  function bsp_badges_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' =>_x('Badges', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' =>_x('Badge', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' =>_x('Add New', 'badge item'),
    'add_new_item' =>__('Add New Badge Item'),
    'edit_item' =>__('Edit Badge Item'),
    'new_item' =>__('New Badge Item'),
    'view_item' =>__('View Badge Item'),
    'search_items' =>__('Search Badge'),
    'not_found' =>__('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' =>__('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 75,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'has_archive'=>true,
    'show_in_menu'=>'badge-school'

    //'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'badge' , $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

One of my taxonomies:

```
     register_taxonomy(
'skills',
array('badge'), 
array(
'hierarchical'=>true,
'public'=>true,
'label'=>'Skills',
'labels'=>array(
    'name'=> _x( 'Skills', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'=>'Skill',
    'menu_name'=>__('Skills')
    ),
'show_ui'=>true,
'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'skill'),
)
);
```

Then I tried adding a submenu like that:

```
    add_action('admin_menu','bsp_plugin_menu');

    function bsp_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('Badge school', 'Badge School', 'manage_options','badge-school','bsp_students_function','dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
    //my taxonomy
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=badge', 'Skills', 'Skills', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?taxonomy=skill&post_type=badge');
```

But it does not show. I see the menu Badges and nothing else. There should also be add new post and it's not showing. I don't know what am I doing wrong and how to fix it. I need to get it all in one menu, because I need to add more submenus without taxonomies.

I hope you can understand my problem, as I mentioned, I don't really know how to ask the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Are you post types / taxonomy *not* showing up in the admin panel or *are* they showing up and you want to add a sub-menu under the Badges Post Type?

Comment: If I do custom post with custom taxonomies everything is fine and it's showing in the admin menu. But when I try to add a new admin menu and then add this custom post with it's taxonomies to show as submenu, then it's not showing. @Howdy_McGee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answear my own question after much googeling:

In the args array I commented out the option for show_in_menu, so that custom post type creates the menu itself. Then I didn't add the admin menu, but just the submenu (the hook still remains).

```
    add_action('admin_menu','bsp_plugin_menu');
```

And the first parameter is the one that shows it in the menu and it is a name of the custom post type:

```
    add_submenu_page(**'edit.php?post_type=badge'**, 'Add new students', 'Add new students', 'manage_options','add-new-students','bsp_students_add');
```

And now it shows in the menu with all the taxonomies and custom post.